# xampp sql console if statement error unrecognized statement

Tags: sql, xampp, subquery

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM doc_submitted WHERE student_IDNUM = 131009685 AND doc_id = 1)) THEN
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `doc_submitted`(`student_IDNUM`, `doc_id`) VALUES (131009685,1)
END
END IF
```

I want to know how can i make that query work.

additional question would be how to make if statement in xampp(latest version)

answered: IF STATEMENT CANT EXIST OUTSIDE STORED PROCEDURE

Answer (score 0):

answered: IF STATEMENT CANT EXIST OUTSIDE STORED PROCEDURE